# Push Notifications to PWA on Android in closed off intranet

Tags: android, intranet, progressive-web-application, push-notifications

We have a custom PWA (Angular frontent, c# web api backend) that is used on mobile android devices (and desktops) within our company facilities. The mobile devices do not have an internet connection.

I now want to implement push notifications similar to e.g. Whatsapp (receivable even if the screen is locked). These are to be pushed by a backend service running on a server within the company network.

Now, the regular push api is working with intermediary endpoints through the FCM server. Off course this requires the mobile devices to be reachable from outside the local intranet which we'd like to avoid.

Is there a feasible solution to send push notifications without an external server?
Or at least set this up with a proxy so that the mobile devices do not have direct access to the internet/the other way around?

Edit:
Requirements sum-up:

- Send push notification from backend service to Angular PWA on android mobile
- Work in enclosed intranet
- Support opening pages in the PWA from the notification
- Be able to receive notifications while PWA is in background or screen is locked (and show them in the lock screen)

Comment: I don't have experience but searching for the keywords `android push on-premise` does return some promising results.

Comment: @Robert Hmm, a bunch of that stuff still seems to use FCM etc.. And for other solutions which don't I couldn't figure out if they fit all the requirements (added a sum-up) like being able to e.g. open pages in the PWA or work even in lock screen.